# How to get information about the app sending notification using notify-send

Tags: linux, notifications

How to get info about the app/process sending the notification using notify-send. say I want to record the name of all the app/process using notification service in current session. What should be the best way to implement this behaviour in a notification daemon if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible with notify-send. notify-send is a program only for sending desktop notifications. Since notifications are usually sent via dbus, dbus recorder programs may point you to the right direction. You may want to check this out https://github.com/victronenergy/dbus-recorder